# Change Toolbar menu item style

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I have textual menu items inside the ToolBar and I need to make them bold, and change their type face.

[image]

1. How to change the style to be bold from the theme?
2. Can I get access to the internal view widget and change it's typeface?

Answer (score 0):

You can set Toolbar style

```
 <style name="DrawerTitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

Also refer following link-

[Change Toolbar Menu Item color (non-hidden action)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352963/change-toolbar-menu-item-color-non-hidden-action)