# Change Toolbar Un-hidden Menu Icon Color

Tags: android

How to change toolbar search icon color? I want it to be white colored. I've change with my own white drawable but the result still black. I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352963/change-toolbar-menu-item-color-non-hidden-action) but the post problem is text color not icon color.

**ScreenShot**

[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.zihadrizkyef.project_katalog_grosirmukenalukis_admin.MainActivity"

    android:id="@+id/activity_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/myToolbarTheme"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvProduct"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**style.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/mybutton</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/myWidgetContentColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/myWidgetContentColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**menu_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: can you show your menu file?

Comment: Have you tried by giving tint color to that icon?

Comment: Can u replace this with mToolBarTheme in style and check? <style name="myToolbarTheme" parent="">
         <item name="android:theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
         <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
         <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark</item>
         <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
     </style>

Comment: add <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item> in your parent AppTheme style

Comment: @himanshu1496 Sorry about that, i am forget to put menu xml in the post

Comment: @MayankPandya how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer :

**main_activity.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/myToolbarTheme"/>
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="myToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Still if you don't want to change the theme and change only searchView color then you can try my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create your own menu, then place your own icon in menu item.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.bruce.example.search.SearchActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Then just overwrite onCreateOptionsMenu to inflate your custom menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Let me know if you have any problem with it

Comment: Thank you. But sorry i've did it, i am forget to tell it in the post.

Comment: I've use my own PNG icon with white colored, but the result is black

Answer (score 1):

put following code into your activity's onCreateOptionsMenu().

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        MenuItem favoriteItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        Drawable newIcon = (Drawable)favoriteItem.getIcon();
        newIcon.mutate().setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 200, 200, 200), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        favoriteItem.setIcon(newIcon);
        return true;
    }
```

You can give your own color in {Color.argb(255, 200, 200, 200)}

Answer (score 0):

create a XML file, you may call it ic_action_search_white, using tint to change the icon color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:tint="@color/white"/>
```

Then in your menu item set `android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search_white"`, the drawable is the XML file just created. Or you can programmatically set the icon `yourSearchMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search_white)`

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Change your `AppTheme` to below:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

Making it dark `actionBar` will solve your problem of menu icon color.

**Update:** Added `windowNoTitle` set as `true`.

Comment: I am using v7 toolbar, it gives me
'java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.'

Comment: okay have you added `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>` in your `AppTheme` style as mentioned in answer, and if the theme is for above Lollipop then add `<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>`.

Comment: Oh sorry. i didn't see the `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>`. After i put it, i got error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }`

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Just now I found out that we need to use both `windowActionBar` and `windowNoTitle` together to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Add following method where the searchView is declared.

```
public Drawable changeDrawableTint(Drawable drawable, int color){
    final Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawable, ColorStateList
            .valueOf(color));
    return wrappedDrawable;
}
```

Now these two lines you've already written

```
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
```

Just add this line

```
// To change the color of searchView
searchItem.setIcon(changeDrawableTint(searchItem.getIcon(), Color.WHITE));
```