# How to change Action Bar text based button color?

Tags: android, text, colors, android-actionbar

I had already had some issues with the overflow button being black and wanting it white but after some trial and error I got it working. But I just can't get this text button to be white. It's just a string based item in the main_toolbar.xml

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/more"
        android:title="@string/more"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

[Link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kk5Z.png)

After playing around for several hours in styles.xml and looking for solutions in here, I gave up and just decided to ask for my specific problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [link_actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352963/change-toolbar-menu-item-color-non-hidden-action?answertab=votes#tab-top) 
hope that can help you

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment but none of the answers there did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the color of the MenuItem text easily by using SpannableString instead of String

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);

int positionOfMenuItem = 0; // or whatever...
MenuItem item = menu.getItem(positionOfMenuItem);
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My red MenuItem");
s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, s.length(), 0);
item.setTitle(s);
}
```

Comment: Ideally I would like to not do it programatically